# my MAC terminal is locked via an 491 erreur under Node What can i do

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I have an error number 491 on my terminal Mac under Node.js
I can't make anything create the new file, Ngrok tunnel, look at this:

What can I do?
Thks

Comment: Last login: Tue Oct 17 10:41:00 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro-de-Gregory% npm start
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
   )
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
  sages [yn]? n
usage: rm [-f | -i] [

Comment: 491 is the line number, can you please add the above to the question.